# Две строки в элементе меню

Tags: java, android

Необходимо динамически добавлять информацию о пользователе (имя + email) в элемент меню. Информация должна быть отображена в две строки в одном элементе.
Уже пытался реализовать так:

```
android:lines="2"
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
android:maxLines="4"
android:singleLine="false"
android:text="First line\nSecond line"?
```

И так:

```
System.getProperty ("line.separator")
\n, \r
string = string.replace("\\\n", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
(Html.fromHtml("text before break<br/>text after break").toString());
```

не все безрезультатно. Буду оченьблагодарен за любую подсказку или помощь!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После нескольких дней поисков решения, пришел к выводу, что в options menu это сделать не представляется возможным. И лучшей (для меня) альтернативой было использование Popup Window. Конечно придется повозиться с разметкой layout'a, но если есть крайняя необходимость (как в моем случае), то это отличное решение.